# Is there a way to put complex (nested) variables in ansible inventory

Tags: ansible, inventory, ansible-inventory

I have an environment variable for the proxy

```
proxy_env:
    http_proxy: myproxy
    https_proxy: myproxy
    ftp_proxy: myproxy
    no_proxy: localhost,127.0.0.1
    proxy_host: myproxy
    proxy_port: 80
```

and now I would like to deploy the same thing on machines that don't need a proxy (therefore I would like to move this variables in the inventory).

However, if I only move the block in the inventory

```
[machinegroup:vars]
proxy_env:
    http_proxy: myproxy
    https_proxy: myproxy
    ftp_proxy: myproxy
    no_proxy: localhost,127.0.0.1
    proxy_host: myproxy
    proxy_port: 80
```

I get an error: "Failed to parse inventory..."

If I put it in one line it is not taken into consideration either...

```
proxy_env http_proxy=myproxy ..
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *Is there a way to put nested variables in ansible inventory?*

A: Yes. It is. Use [YAML](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-hosts-and-groups) format.

```
all:
    hosts:
        test1:
        test2:
            proxy_env:
                http_proxy: myproxy
                https_proxy: myproxy
                ftp_proxy: myproxy
                no_proxy: localhost,127.0.0.1
                proxy_host: myproxy
                proxy_port: 80
```

---

INI format is also possible, but not very practical in this case.

```
test2 proxy_env={{http_proxy: myproxy},{https_proxy: myproxy}, ... }
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this site - https://everythingshouldbevirtual.com/automation/ansible-using-yaml-for-inventory/ - has an example that seems a bit more clear to me.